# Canberra-gtk-play "failed to play sound" for two wav files

Tags: sound, gtk, wav

I'm using `canberra-gtk-play` to play a number of wav files, but it doesn't work with two of the files that I downloaded from freesound.org. Other files work fine. I'm quite sure that I've got the right path, because everything is in the same folder and

`canberra-gtk-play -f ~/Schreibtisch/file1.wav`

works fine, but

`canberra-gtk-play -f ~/Schreibtisch/file2.wav`

returns

`Failed to play sound: Operation not supported`

Either file plays fine if I just double click them as usual.
I haven't been able to find any info on that error message, either. It only happens with files downloaded from freesound.org - does that have anything to do with it?
Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Comment: Can you give a direct link to some of the files that are failing?